# How can I make a notebook with two column layout?

Tags: output-formatting

How can I make a notebook with two column layout?

Is it possible? I saw something tools could do such thing? Author Tools?

Comment: Equivalent question on Stack Overflow: [(S.O.7135572)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7135572/618728) -- +1 and hoping for newer/better methods.

Comment: In general I would really like to see Wolfram add new features to the notebook editor.

Answer (score 3):

Is this question about using two column in the Mathematica Frontend (and do you need the flow of text to be automatic from one to the next column). Then the answer is no not possible. 
or is it about generating a report with multiple columns. Then yes possible but not with auto flow.