# Is there a way to create a two column page layout in a notebook?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I am working on a white-paper that requires a two column format.  Is there an existing Stylesheet that can be used or a way to create a Stylesheet that supports this Mathematica?

Comment: You can format output with `Grid` and friends but in general: [30440](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30440/5478)

Comment: Use Mathematica for computation and graphics, which is what it is best at, and use Latex for typesetting which is what it is best at.

Comment: Hi Koba - Thanks for the references.  Looking at the questions on a two column layout, this may be too cumbersome and a bridge too far to program, debug and submit under a tight deadline.

Comment: To assure that a particular reader sees your comments addressed to him or her, use (for instance) @Nasser rather just Nasser.  (You, on the other hand, automatically see all comments on your own question.)